# C# .Net script error when removing chrome=1 from meta tag

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome

We have an MVC3 C# .Net web app.  We had been using chrome=1 in the X-UA-Compatible meta tag.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
```

Our internal customer, however, doesn't like the look and usage of Chrome.  So, we have removed chrome=1 from the meta tag.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

We are now seeing the following script error.

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; chromeframe/32.0.1700.76; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Thu, 23 Jan 2014 19:24:44 UTC


Message: Script error
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: http://creative.xtendmedia.com/matomy/mmpop/mmpop.js?mm_an=ply&a=15041105&context=c15001117&size=800x600


Message: Script error
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: http://192.168.244.179:15871/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi?ws-session=141377712
```

Unfortunately, ChromeFrame is a standard add-on in our Corporate environment and will not be removed from the servers.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

EDIT:
This appears to be a Chrome Frame issue.  [Chrome Frame Issue](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/cgXLAjIAPQA)

Also: [Users upset at Google for changing scroll controls](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57617308-93/chrome-users-mad-at-google-for-switching-up-scroll-controls/)

The scroll bars don't work properly, that's why we removed the chrome=1 from the tag.  If the scroll bars worked right, we would be good to go

Comment: Interestingly it looks like you didn't have a valid version of the tag before according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx (it mentions nothing about putting chrome stuff in there). Is it possible that it would be better with no tag at all? edge seems to be the latest and equivalent to an HTML 5 doctype...

Comment: @Chris...I tried with not tag and still received the script error

Comment: Ah. I've not come across ChromeFrame before. That's me out of thoughts but good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing your customer does not like is the meta tag in the source of the page, you can use the HTTP Header instead. Just modify your web.config and add it as a custom header.

The following should provide you with the information you need

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders

Comment: @A Thanks, I'll check that out.  WHat is it you are suggesting I put in the web.config file

Comment: @A  I don't think this is the answer I need.  We need to take out the chrome=1 tag because the user doesn't like how the web site looks using chrome.  It's not the tag they don't like, it's how chrome makes the web site behave they don't like

Comment: @MikeTWebb another option is to use an alternate DOCTYPE, sometimes that can help mitigate some cross browser issues. Aside of complete CSS rework....

Comment: If the customer doesn't like how it displays in chrome but it doesn't work in any other browser then I think you have to tell him to suck it up or rework how it works in chrome...